# Using table rows as form elements with MVC model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have an MVC5/Bootstrap application that has a page where the user, as part of a larger form, can add and delete rows in a table.

To add rows, the user clicks an icon and then searches for data using a TypeAhead field that appears in a popover, which when selected retrieves row data using AJAX and inserts the row into the table.

Rows can be deleted by clicking on an icon in each row, the row is then removed. Both these actions affect a bound hidden input field that contains a list of IDs of the rows, e.g. "{100001},{100003},{100004}".

When the form that contains this table is submitted this hidden field is parsed and the appropriate database actions are performed using EF6 to add or delete items.

My question is whether this approach of using a single hidden field that is manually parsed by the controller method is the best choice. I was thinking there may be a more idiomatic way to utilize MVC model binding. e.g. having hidden checkboxes on each row or some such mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModel you are binding to could contain a collection of row viewmodels that wrap all inputs for a single row.

To submit these, bind them using the index.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
               @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RowData[0].SomeRowProperty)
               <input type="hidden" name="RowData.Index" value="0" />
        </td>     
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
               @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RowData[1].SomeRowProperty)
               <input type="hidden" name="RowData.Index" value="1" />      
        </td>     
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See also [Model binding to a list](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)